# Are globals considered as statements?

Tags: c, global

This might be a simple question, but are globals, and anything written outside of a function (structs, enums, functions...), considered as statements? If so, are all of them statements, or only some of them?

Comment: [Statements in C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/statements-c).

Comment: The formal language grammar contains categories _expressions_, _declarations_, _statements_ and _external definitions_. You can download the C standard (google C11 draft) then check Annex A for a summary of the formal language grammar.

Comment: @Lundin: Reading the C standard you advise using reveals the formal language grammar does not contain any *external definitions* category. Following the substitutions in the grammar shows a *translation-unit* can be considered as a sequence of *function-definition* and *declaration* items outside of functions and *declaration* and *statement* items inside functions, so there would be three categories, *function-definition*, *declaration*, and *statement*. An *expression* is not a category on this level…

Comment: …  There is a heavily-used *expression-statement* item in the grammar, of course, but it is a subdivision of *statement*, so, if it is a category of things you find in a C program, then so should be its siblings *compound-statement*, *expression-statement*, *selection-statement*, *iteration-statement*, and *jump-statement*. Blithely telling somebody to check the grammar in the C standard while giving them wrong information about it is not helpful. Somebody new to the standard would not be expected to figure out how your categories match the grammar, since they do not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Chapter A.2.4 "External definitions" disagrees with you.

Comment: @Lundin: Chapter titles are not part of the grammar, especially when you explicitly refer to “The formal language grammar.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the formal C grammar, a *translation-unit*, which is the sequence of tokens resulting from reading one source file and applying “preprocessing” to it (including macro replacement and inclusion of files via `#include`), consists of *function-definition* and *declaration* items. These are not statements.

A *function-definition* both declares a function (makes its name known to the compiler) and defines it (provides code for the body of a function, in a *compound-statement* that starts with `{` and ends with `}`).

Inside the *compound-statement* there are *declaration* and *statement* items. A *declaration* says something about some identifier (a name used for some an object, function, structure tag, typedef name, or member of a structure, union, or enumeration).

So, when a variable is declared outside of any function, it is in a *declaration*, not in a *statement*.

Some declarations are also definitions, but this distinction is not made directly in the formal grammar.